# CSS Grid wrap without repeat and auto-fill?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 3 columns in my grid.

I want them to behave like this:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

as shown in this codepen: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/xBmYJN

Except i want it to be only 3 columns per row and the last column to be 3fr (3x the size of the other 2 columns), i.e. "1fr 1fr 3fr".
And i want the last column to automatically go to a new row when its minimum width is met.

When using the above example the columns automatically collapse to a new row when they dont fit. Is there a way to do this in my case? Without manually configuring grid-template-areas and adjusting them depending on @media screen width?

I assume the functionality comes from the auto-fill argument of repeat()...

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid>div {
  background: #EDE7F6;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: 12px system-ui;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Esse aliquid laboriosam minima ex praesentium recusandae reprehenderit unde sit tempore atque aut commodi quae expedita corrupti, dignissimos architecto. Eius, maiores ad?</div>
  <div>Quibusdam, eos esse dolorum facere voluptatem eius, dolore quas totam aspernatur obcaecati harum? Nihil eligendi eos minus odit minima earum incidunt rem fugit reprehenderit, molestiae possimus eveniet itaque laudantium excepturi.</div>
  <div>Ducimus quibusdam inventore delectus doloribus dignissimos. Dignissimos quos officia minus exercitationem perspiciatis harum iusto molestiae deleniti quod sunt amet recusandae autem, neque doloremque ad alias eaque consequuntur nesciunt quis eius!</div>
  <div>Cumque aspernatur ex ipsum dolorum eius, tempore omnis minus sequi architecto totam sunt maxime nemo, ab repellendus. Aut voluptatem saepe voluptatibus nisi ipsum. Debitis corporis culpa ipsa error nemo doloribus.</div>
  <div>Consequatur dolore, architecto quos saepe consequuntur libero minus totam? Enim optio provident commodi corporis officiis, sunt maiores? Cupiditate consequuntur, cumque natus corporis velit sunt ad magni aliquid facere deleniti molestiae.</div>
  <div>Voluptatibus similique modi voluptatum voluptatem quo quod minima ducimus facere, sequi libero accusamus nisi nobis? Minima error tempore quo esse quod odit, deleniti labore nulla ullam velit nemo neque sint!</div>
  <div>Qui, corporis delectus? Pariatur vel autem commodi, accusantium, voluptate obcaecati iste, a debitis facilis repellendus mollitia. Dolore dicta totam, quaerat omnis accusantium magni alias voluptates eligendi ex id aut dolorem?</div>
  <div>Recusandae tempora ab error omnis exercitationem illo accusamus esse sit ipsa accusantium iure, possimus ducimus quis consequuntur qui corporis nobis culpa repudiandae! Suscipit, debitis. Omnis delectus at vitae laborum quos?</div>
  <div>Dolorem saepe accusamus sed placeat porro ex, ab, vel eaque libero incidunt facilis delectus, iure odio dicta error consequuntur perspiciatis quasi? Corrupti incidunt quia asperiores quo magnam at minima laudantium?</div>
  <div>Dolor ad saepe, nemo fugit tempora autem est fugiat quis porro atque nam repellendus maxime neque voluptatem rerum amet odit aspernatur voluptates iusto eos laboriosam enim vel. Eius, debitis beatae!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically no.. There is not.

Comment: Would you do this with media queries? :/

Comment: i guess i can just do it flex and wrap.. just wanted to try and use grid ^^

Comment: here is an idea but failing while leaving a empty gap (if no mediaquerie + max-width set) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjbJgNo , if anyone else can use it ;) not too sure about the size of the third column once wrapped ? spanning the other 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. The trick is to assign your third column to span 3 columns while leaving the `grid-template-column` to `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`.

Also, by using `auto-fit` the columns will adjust a bit nicer as they fit available space.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

div.col3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">First</div>
  <div class="col2">Second</div>
  <div class="col3">Third</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jstensved/pen/OJEoaQQ)

Comment: This answers the question if there is only 3 divs - however, I think OPs question is looking for an automatic solution **without** using a class (if you look at the codepen and snippet examples provided) for the third child. Essentially it would be `1fr 1fr 3fr` for every row and then when it collapses `1.5fr 1.5fr` with the `3fr` falling below onto a separate row.